# Opportunity Team Member to Opportunity above the Role hierarchy

Tags: roles, opportunity-teams

I want to Add myself as 'Opportunity Team Member' even of the Opportunity is way above my User's Role Hierarchy Level.

Now, as per the Salesforce, I must be the Owner of the Opportunity or I should have 'Modify All' Permission in order to do what I want. I cannot Provide 'Modify All' permission as it gives additional permissions(like delete permission) to the user which I don't want.

Now, what am asking is for direction, which could be a possible *workaround* to this issue.

Comment: where you are trying to do this, in Apex code?

Comment: No, I was first trying it in Configuration part by using custom VF pages and Button but ended up having the same issue that I don't have the level of access necessary to perform the operation.

Comment: You can use VF+ Apex in without sharing

Comment: I tried using Without Sharing in my extension class, but the issue is the same.

Answer (score 1):

We took the Flow approach.  Set up a Screen Flow component on Opp Record and set to run as system to bypass sharing, ownership and role hierarchy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could setup Opportunity Team and be part of the team. You can think of default Opportunity team for an Opportunity.

When you set up an opportunity team, you:

- Add team members.
- Specify each member’s role on the opportunity, such as Executive Sponsor.
- Specify each team member’s level of access to the opportunity: read/write access or read-only access.

> Only the opportunity’s owner or users above the owner in the role hierarchy can add, edit, or delete opportunity team members.

You can’t use opportunity teams for private opportunities.

Refer [Guidelines for Using Opportunity Teams](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=salesteam_def.htm&type=5)

So, you cannot pull any other's Opportunity and can able to create Opportunity Team as it could break access policies.

Also, you can create a screen to notify Opportunity Owner to add you in the Opportunity team. It could make more sense to Business.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've gone through all the documentation and already knew some of the things you mentioned. What I am thinking is to use a Custom Object and use it to trigger to save standard Opportunity Team records. I don't wanna do that.

Comment: Better to leverage OOTB functionality, and setup a process to achieve it.